# Loop Over Multiple Environment Objects R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, janitor

I want to be able to loop over multiple objects in my environment and do some data cleaning on each data frame. Is there a more efficient way to do what I am doing below in 1 call?

```
df1 %>%
clean_names()

df2 %>% 
clean_names()

df3 %>%
clean_names()

etc.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to akrun´s answer, you can also filter objects from your global environment by class.
I recommend you store the updated dataframe in a list, not in the global environment, but in case you want that you can use `list2env`.

```
library(purrr)

mget(ls()) %>%
keep(is.data.frame) %>%
map(janitor::clean_names) %>%
##(DISCLAIMER - this replaces the original data.frames in your global environment, and could be dangerous:)
list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: How do I make this store the cleaned names in my environment objects, and not just print to the console?

Comment: I strongly recommend you keep the objects in a list, and not the Global Env. Should you really want to get them back into the global env, see my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

Base R

```
library(janitor) # for clean_names function
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

lapply(dfs, clean_names)
```

Comment: Although I use `is.x` fuctions a lot, I did not know this `is()`function. Seems very usefull to have a universal `is()`. Thanks

Comment: @TarJae Works, but when I run the second line of code it just prints the now "cleaned data frames" to the console. How do I make sure the clean names are stored in the environment objects?

Comment: assign it to an object like `x1 <- lapply(dfs, clean_names)`

Answer (score 4):

Get all the objects created in the environment with `mget` into a `list` and then loop over the `list` and apply the function

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
out <- map(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$')), ~ .x %>%
      clean_names())
```

The `pattern` in `ls` subset the object names based on the regex pattern that check for objects with names that starts (`^`) with `df` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string